# Error "In a grant or revoke statement, the user attempted to grant a tablespace quota above the upper limit." when trying to increase user quota

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, tablespaces

I'm attempting to increase the space quota on a particular schema. I'm using the following query to do so:

```
ALTER USER MY_SCHEMA QUOTA "100 M" ON "USERS";
```

This results in the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-02187: invalid quota specification
02187. 00000 -  "invalid quota specification"
*Cause:    In a grant or revoke statement, the user attempted to grant
           a tablespace quota above the upper limit.
*Action:   Grant a smaller tablespace quota.
```

But this doesn't make any sense. The user already has a 50 MB quota, and a query trying to set it to 25 MB fails with the same error message:

```
ALTER USER MY_SCHEMA QUOTA "25 M" ON "USERS";
```

I've confirmed that my tablespace has enough room left. (Its data files can acquire about 2 GB more of disk space.) What is causing this error?

Comment: I figured this out while writing the question and decided to post it anyway and self answer since it drove me bonkers for about a half hour or 45 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the error message is misleading. The problem is the quoting around the size specification.

Both of these work:

```
ALTER USER MY_SCHEMA QUOTA 100M ON "USERS";
```

and

```
ALTER USER MY_SCHEMA QUOTA 100 M ON "USERS";
```